# When are all Gorenstein projective also pure-injective?

Tags: representation-theory, homological-algebra

For an artin algebra of finite global dimension, each Gorenstein projective module is projective then is pure-injective. Are there any other examples having this property?
That is, all Gorenstein projective modules are pure-injective.